# iPhone Localization without English

Tags: iphone, localization, localizable.strings

I have an app that's only supported in Dutch and French. English is not an available language for this app. 
If I want to use localizable strings, the default always gets set on English. I want this to be dutch. 
So what I did was use the English localizable strings file and fill it up with dutch words. Only problem I have is that it shows English as a supported Language in the App Store. Is there any way to change the default Localizable Strings file to Dutch so that the only two languages that show up are Dutch and French?

Thanks in advance,

Lewion

Answer (score 1):

You should rename the folder where your dutch files lay in from `en.lproj` to `nl.lproj`. Everything should still work then but the language will get recognized correctly. You may have to tell Xcode about the new location of the files.

Comment: Doesn't work. If I rename that folder and tell Xcode it's location, he adds the name as Localizable.strings instead of nl (or Dutch for that matter), and it defaults in french because it can't read the dutch strings file anymore somehow...

Comment: You have to point him to each file separately. Alternatively: add dutch as language to all files, then replace them with the english ones and remove english in xcode

Answer (score 1):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
      setObject:[NSDictionary 
                  dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nl", nil]
                  forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]];
```

That will make Dutch the default language.

Comment: But then English will still show up as a supported language in iTunes Connect.. And it doesn't solve the problem with the localization files.

Answer (score 0):

Create Dutch and French by standard means and delete **English.lproj** from the app after building, for example as a build phase, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app/4094880#4094880) (2nd paragraph).