# iPhone - support many languages, but include only one in bundle

Tags: iphone, localization, bundle

I want to develop application in Xcode for many languages. So I have resources localized for those languages. But is this possible to remove from final bundle all localized resources, and left them only for one language?

For example: I develop application for German and English language, but I want to build the bundle only with German.lproj, and without English.lproj. I want to to this, because my resource files are quite big, and I don't want to include for example English images in German version.

I've tried to remove English.lproj from bundle, but then I cannot install application on my device, because the message is that the resources have been modified (which is quite true). I think that bundle is signed or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create multiple targets for your different languages.  Keep the resources in the project. Create a new target. Remove (or don't add) those resources from the new target.

Comment: But it removes bundle completely... I don't know if you've understood me well. I want to remove those additional language resources only from built bundle, but have them all the time in my project (for example, for future builds etc.).

Comment: Oh. I understand now. Keep the resources in the project. Create a new target. Remove those resources from the new target.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need. Also here is some tip how to remove specific language resources from the bundle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app/4094880#4094880

Comment: @Marcin - Glad to hear it helped. Feel free to select this answer as correct. ;-)