# Detect language in use by iOS application

Tags: objective-c, nslocale

How can I detect the current application language ? I am not talking about `NSLocale` user preferences.

In my app there are currently two supported languages. A default 'en' and a specific 'it'.

I just wanted to know which one is actually in use. If it is relevant, as a further explanation, I am providing content trough a web service only for the two supported languages. When invoking the service I need to pass a language parameter. Currently I am doing this, it works, but I totally dislike it:

```
NSString *preferredLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

if (![preferredLanguage isEqualToString:@"it"] && ![preferredLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
    return @"en";
}
return preferredLanguage;
```

I have looked trough the `NSLocale` `class` and `UIApplication`, but didn't manage to find anything useful.

I also notice that `NSBundle` has some localization methods, but they all seems not specific about which one is in use.

Comment: Gwendal's suggestion is ok. But, I see no reason why you dislike the method you are using. According to the [docs][1], this is the method that

> Returns the user's language preference order as an array of strings

Why look for another?

  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually reserve a special key in Localizable.strings, such as "HTTPAcceptLanguage", which I set to "en", "fr", etc. Now telling your server the language displayed by the application is as simple as NSLocalizedString(@"HTTPAcceptLanguage", nil).

Comment: Nice and it works. Give me more time for listening to other suggestion, then I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Since your goal is to have the server provide its response in the exact same language as the one used by your app, and avoid any localization mismatch at all cost, I think that solution is optimal as it does exactly express the intention. But take your time :-)

Answer (score 4):

`[[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0]` would be better, because it will always return a localization that your app supports. There is no need for an additional check afterwards.

In fact, your code has a bug. If the first language in the user's preferences is not one that your app supports, iOS will continue down the list until it finds one that your app does support. So if the user's preferences were `"fr", "it", "en", ...`, iOS would load the `it` versions of your resources. However, your code would fall back to `en`.

(This is perhaps more important on OS X, where it's easy for the user to change the language ordering. On iOS it's [apparently possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app#comment4458844_4094880) to do that, but it's not as obvious how it works.)

Comment: This approach has an issue : the bundle may return something like fr_FR, fr_CA, en_UK, etc. The NSLocalizedString technique, on the contrary, makes it clear that server may not have the same language support as iOS, and also makes it easy to explicitly choose the server language for each iOS locale identifier.