# App localization approaches pros and cons?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I'm preparing to support another language of an app, and actually I can see two ways to do this:

**Localize** the app **with the developer tools**, the approach like http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios (this depends on the language settings of the particular device).

**Provide a separate app** in the particular AppStore that is localized "statically". (this depends on the AppStore the user downloaded the app from).

What approaches did you use in production along which considerations? Can you give me some real-world examples of pros and cons of each approach? Which one do you suggest?

Comment: I expected closing votes, I just wanted to hear best practices. Actually to reinforce my bias towards version a.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app?rq=1) in detail. Basically, you do not want to force the user to a specific language. The OS already has heuristics built in to match the languages supported by your app with the user language settings.