# Set Base Language to Settings.Bundle iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, settings.bundle

How do i add base language in settings bundle.

In my project, i have added two .strings file (french and english) inside settings bundle. I could see the languages reflecting on my app under iPhone settings screen. But when i select different language other than above two languages, the last shown language is displaying. for eg, if i select french as my default language, it is showing french but when i select swedish as my language (i have no swedish language in project), it still shows french. But i need to show English as Base Language. This is working on Localizable.strings inside the project. But this is not reflecting on settings bundle.

Any Idea!

Comment: is there is any solution? to set default English language

Answer (score 0):

Base language is not a "default language". In fact, in iOS doesn't exist the concept of default language as you think. See the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754890/nslocalizedstring-not-defaulting-to-base-language).