# Finding the current localization of iOS app in code

Tags: ios, localization

Connected issue: [Non-English default language for iOS App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app)

I am wondering how to check the current localization of my app in code.
For example:
I want to check if the app is running with German localization (.strings, storyboard)
This line of code:

```
[[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"de"]
```

doesn't provide the correct answer. Because if a user's language list in device settings looks like this for example (french, german, english) and we have only localization for english and german, application is launched in german but the above condition isn't fulfilled.

Comment: Did you mean, you have several localization for your app (english and german) and you want to know witch one is currently use (i.e.,  if user set preferred language to French, you want to know if english or german is used) ? If this is right, just create a localized string named useLanguage and in your english translation translate to english and in your german translation translate de german... Could this solve your request ? `NSString *useLanguage = NSLocalizedString (@"useLanguage", @"This is the curent use language : en, de,...");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My naive solution would be to create a localized string "LanguageCode" which is set to "de" in the german string file and to "en" in the english string file

e.g.:

```
if ([NSLocalizedString(@"LanguageCode", @"en, de etc.") isEqualToString:@"de"]) {
    // german
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will return a two letter code for the currently selected language. "en" for English, "es" for Spanish, "de" for German, etc. For more examples, please see this Wikipedia entry (in particular, the 639-1 column):

Answer (score 1):

Check the first entry of `Bundle`'s [preferredLocalizations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1413220-preferredlocalizations) property, which is:

> an array of NSString objects containing language IDs for localizations
>   in the bundle. The strings are ordered according to the user's
>   language preferences and available localizations.

For example, if you're checking to see if your German localization are being used:

```
if Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first == "de" {
   // Is using German
}
```