# How to set Default Localization Language to German instead of English in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to set default localization language to German. However , it is always showing text in English language. Can anyone guide me through proper steps to set the default language to German, so that no matter what language is selected in iPhone, it always displays text in German. I will be using German and french localization otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-English default language for iOS App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app)

Answer (score 1):

In the Info.plist file, set the 'Localization native development region' (`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`) to the region at your choice.

For example:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>esES</string>
```