# Is it possible set default English on app setting bundle display name?

Tags: ios, resourcebundle, setting

How can i change the App Setting bundle display name to English by default,if user selects the non- localized language through device language settings?

—> User selected language as **English**,it displays the **English** content

—> User changed the language to **French**,app supports **French**,app name displayed in **French**.

—> User again selected the non-localised language(**Chinese**) through device settings,but App wont supports to this language,it should display the App name to English.But it not displaying the English instead it showed the Previous supported German language app name.

Can anybody help me,is it possible or not?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I'm asking for app setting bundle display content to keep default in English . If I select non-localized language

Comment: Try this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1828/_index.html